How to get the values in a list with specific indices in Python?
For instance, I have
list_a = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]

list_b = [10, 11, 12, nan, nan, nan, 16]

list_b is the indices of list_a, starting from 10 instead of 0. The nan elements means that the corresponding data is not of interest. The list I need is
list_c = [10, 20, 30, nan, nan, nan, 70]. How can I get it?

A simple list comprehension should get you what you want:
>>> [list_a[i] if list_b[i] is not nan else nan for i, val in enumerate(list_b)]
[10, 20, 30, nan, nan, nan, 70]

Here we're effectively ignoring the non-nan values in list_b; we're just treating it like a list of "boolean" nan/not-nan values.
I guess a more accurate reflection of what you wanted would be:
>>> [list_a[list_b[i]-10] if list_b[i] is not nan else nan for i, val in enumerate(list_b)]
[10, 20, 30, nan, nan, nan, 70]

But that gets you the same thing as long as the values in list_b are just an incrementing sequence (when they're not nan).

if list_b[i] is not nan is not the correct way to check if an object is a float object with value NaN (leaving aside that nan would raise a NameError)

Maybe? It works and produces the correct result. I guess technically we should be using numpy.isnan().

No, it doesn't work. data = [float('nan'), float('nan')]; nan = float('nan'); print([x is not nan for x in data]

OP never mentioned numpy, and only talked about lists. In plain python, you would use math.isnan, although, I wouldn't be surprised if the OP is using numpy, the question isn't well specified to begin with (again, the NameError)
